# Is it possible to read a geotag from a photo for use in google maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to see if it is possible to read a geotag from a photo using javascript. I would specifically like to do this for use in the google maps API. I know this is probably done on the server side most of the time, but I would like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geotag data is stored as long/lat in the EXIF, and there is a client-side implementation of [exif parser](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/reading-exif-data-with-javascript.html).

Comment: Link is broken but found [this one](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js) instead